# Informatica BDE Hive dynamic Partitions

Tags: hadoop, hive, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Does Informatica have a way to deal with hive partitioning after it does a hive mapping?

For example, imagine data is coming in from a database, and informatica BDE writes the files into an HDFS directory. A hive External table sits on top of that HDFS directory and now needs to add that partition. (ex. hive -e "ALTER TABLE cr.employee ADD PARTITION (par_date='20150824') location '/data/cr/employee/20150824'").

Can this be done natively to informatica bde or do we need to schedule a seperate job (ex. shell script) to do this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in below two ways

1) Create an external partition table and load the data into HIVE table instead of HDFS files and also make sure to set the below properties in the environment sql of the HIVE connection properties

SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;

2) If you want to load this into HDFS files, then you need to add a command task which will call you hcat to alter/create the partitions